# Setting wordpress login page as first page

Tags: wordpress

I have created a ticketing support site in wordpress for which I have to set the wordpress login page 
which is wp-login.php as the first page before the home page.

So can any1 please suggest how to set the wordpress login page in the theme which we use as the first page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want people to log in before accessing your site?

Comment: Yes.I want people to first login to the site.

Comment: You can have a look at the functions inside https://github.com/rrikesh/force-login - The plugin does what you need.